# How to rank with multiple paritions in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, rank

Hi if I have the following table

```
id    code     year
--    ----     ----
1     a        2000
1     b        2001
1     b        2002
1     b        2003
1     c        2007
2     a        1997
3     f        2006
3     f        2014
3     a        2015
```

I want to be able to rank the rows by partitioning on `id` and `code` while ordering by `year`:

```
id    code     year     ranked
--    ----     ----     ------
1     a        2000     1 
1     b        2001     2
1     b        2002     2
1     b        2003     2
1     c        2007     3
2     a        1997     1
3     f        2006     1
3     f        2014     1
3     a        2015     2
```

I have tried doing:

```
select distinct id, code, dense_rank() over(partition by id,code order by year) as ranked
```

however this has resulted in

```
id    code     year     ranked
--    ----     ----     ------
1     a        2000     1 
1     b        2001     2
1     b        2002     3
1     b        2003     4
1     c        2007     5
2     a        1997     1
3     f        2006     1
3     f        2014     2
3     a        2015     3
```

i.e. it appears to have only partitioned on `id`

I have tried `rank()` and `row_number()` too but these do not give the desired table. Am I missing something? I am sure dense_rank is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `dense_rank()`.

```
select id, code, year,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by code) as rank;
from t;
```

However, this doesn't quite do what you want, because the codes are ordered alphabetically and you appear to want the ordering by the minimum of the year.  So, use two levels of window functions:

```
select id, code, year, 
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by minyear) as rank
from (select id, code, year,
             min(year) over (partition by id, code) as minyear
      from t
     ) t;
```